# return all keys of nested array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

given a nested array of arbitrary depth like this:

```
$array = array(
            1400=> 
                array(7300=>
                        array(
                            7301=> array(),
                            7302=> array(),
                            7305=> array(
                                7306=>array()
                            ),
                        ),
                    7314=>array()
                ),
            );
```

how would one get the hierarchy of keys for any key.

for example:

getkeys(7305);

should return 1400,7300,7305 in that order

or

getkeys(7314);

should return 1400,7314

all array keys are unique values

Comment: array_walk with a secondary array to store references to.

Comment: @MiDri if can please make an answer. not sure what you mean.

Comment: [Read array_walk documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) should be straight forward after that.

Comment: @MiDri read it. not at all straight forward to me

Comment: It's not a straight forward thing to do, you need to write a recursive function that array_walk can call to comb the array of arrays.

Comment: doesn't `array_walk` dont present the key if value is an array??

Answer (score 2):

Using [RecursiveIteratorIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php)

```
$array = array(
  1400 => array(
    7300 => array(
      7301=> array(),
      7302 => array(),
      7305 => array(
        7306=>array()
      ),
    ),
    7314=>array()
  ),
);

function getKeys($key, $array) {
  $found_path = [];
  $ritit = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

  foreach ($ritit as $leafValue) {

    $path = array();
    foreach (range(0, $ritit->getDepth()) as $depth) {
      $path[] = $ritit->getSubIterator($depth)->key();
    }

    if (end($path) == $key) {
      $found_path = $path;
      break;
    }
  }

  return $found_path;
}

print_r(getKeys(7305, $array));
// Array
// (
//     [0] => 1400
//     [1] => 7300
//     [2] => 7305
// )
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to check current array branch, and if the needle key isn't found, then iterate current items and check their array child nodes by recursive function calls. Before each step down we push a current key to stack, and pop the stack if the function does not found a needle key in whole branch. So if the key found, the function returns true by the chain, preserving successful keys in the stack.

```
function branchTraversing(& $branch, & $key_stack, $needle_key) {
  $found = false;
  if (!array_key_exists($needle_key, $branch)) {
    reset($branch);
    while (!$found && (list($key, $next_branch) = each($branch))) {
      if (is_array($next_branch)) {
        array_push($key_stack, $key);
        $found = branchTraversing($next_branch, $key_stack, $needle_key);
        if (!$found) {
          array_pop($key_stack);
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    array_push($key_stack, $needle_key);
    $found = true;
  }

  return $found;
}

function getPath(& $array, $needle_key) {
  $path = [];
  branchTraversing($array, $path, $needle_key);
  return $path;
}

$test_keys = [1400, 7300, 7302, 7306, 7314, 666];

foreach ($test_keys as $search_key) {
  echo '<p>' . $search_key . ' => [ '
  . implode(', ', getPath($array, $search_key)) . ' ]</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very interesting problem you have so I tried to make a function that will echo your keys. If this is not good enough pls let me know I can improve code. Thanks.

```
<?php

$a = array(
            1400=> 
                array(7300=>
                        array(
                            7301=> array(),
                            7302=> array(),
                            7305=> array(
                                7306=>array()
                            ),
                        ),
                    7314=>array()
                ),
            );

$mykey = 7306;
$level = 0;
$result = array();
$resultarray = test($a,$mykey,$level,$result);

function test($array,$mykey,$level,$result){
    $level++;
    foreach($array as $key => $element){
        if($key == $mykey){
            echo 'found';
            print_r($result);
            exit;
        } else if(is_array($element)){
            $result[$level] = $key;
            $result1 = test($element,$mykey,$level,$result);
        }
    }
}
```